# Keep email password secure for Node JS automatic email system

Tags: passwords, email, password-management, javascript, node.js

I have a Node JS app running on a cloud server. Part of the app requires validating users' emails, and this validation is done in the standard way: send email to user, user presses link, update database details, celebrate.

To send the email, I use the [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/about/) module. This module requires a username and password of a valid email account in order to send the email. There are two problems with this:

1. Simply putting the password in plaintext seems like a bad thing
2. I think it is possible that it has already been breached, since I am no longer able to log in to the account, neither from the server nor from their website (don't worry, no big deal)

   - Actually, it may not have been breached, but:

   > Access to your account has been temporarily restricted as Yandex<sup>1</sup> suspects it may have been hacked. This may have happened because you have entered your password on a fraudulent website or because your computer is infected with a virus.

   Maybe this "fraudulent website" is my server, but I have been able to send emails automatically with this account not long ago, so I'm not sure.

I was considering two step verification with a single-app password, but I am not sure that that would even help since that password would exist in plain text just like the normal password.

What is the best way to set up this email account and store its username/password to be used automatically by the server?

---

<sup>1</sup> The email service I was using was Yandex because they asked for very little information.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that message is the result of your password being leaked. More likely Yandex noticed that your app is sending a large number of emails in an automated fashion via that address, so their anti-spam system flagged it as "hacked".

Comment: @Ajedi32, do you know if it is possible to disable that?

Comment: No idea, but I'd guess not. Webmail accounts like Yandex aren't really meant to be used the way you're using them here. That's why commercial services like Sendgrid exist.

Comment: @Ajedi32, do you know if there exists something free? I think security settings beyond a strong password are a non-issue given this is used only for automatic emails, right?

Comment: Not of the top of my head, no.